# Rails route for api on subdomain

Tags: api, routes, subdomain, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to make the API of my Rails app accessible through a subdomain (https://api.domain.com). I have the following routes defined:

```
constraints :subdomain => 'api' do
  namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      resources :posts
    end
  end
end
```

This works but results in the following url:

```
https://api.domain.com/api/posts
```

I would like it to be:

```
https://api.domain.com/posts
```

The API controllers are in **app/controllers/api/v1** where they should stay.

I tried mapping the route but without any success. Does somebody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Change

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
```

to

```
namespace :api, path: nil, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
```